# How can I compare 2 Cosmos database containers to see if they contain identical data payloads in the documents?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have 2 CosmosDB containers of documents which should have identical values in the json payloads.  I don't expect the system fields (_rid, _self, _etag, _attachments, _ts) to match.  Is there a tool that can be quickly used to compare properties from 2 containers for differences? Or should I just write come code to go through the docs and compare them?  Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no tool that would do the comparison for you. You will need to write code for that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As Guarav Mantri suggested, I wasn't able to find a tool so I developed code to do the comparison. Thank you.